# Nested SQL and calculated field with WHERE CLAUSE ISSUE

Tags: sql, oracle11g, where-clause, average

I am trying to make the following query work:

```
SELECT m.name,s.category,
'$' || cast((select avg(retail) from STOCK
              INNER JOIN MANUFACTURER
              ON STOCK.DEALERID=MANUFACTURER.DEALERID
               WHERE s.category='sedan' or s.category='suv') 
               as decimal(4,2)) as AVG_RRP 
 from manufacturer m 
      join stock s 
      using (DEALERID)
       WHERE (select(sum(retail) from stock)/
              (select count(distinct category) from manufacturer)) >5000
```

Output required:

- I want to show manufacturer name and stock category
- I want to produce a  calculated field where i find the average retail price for HONDA and GM formatted as $XX.XX
- I want to also list the average retail price for all categories is more than 5000

TABLE FORMAT:

```
MANFACTURER: DEALERID#,name,phone,state
STOCK: VIN#,name,pudate,dealerid,cost,retail,sdiscount,category
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
Manufactuer Name - Stock Category - (Calculated Field)
Honda              Sedan            $XX.XX
```

I am using oracle 11g isql

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql` tag when you're not using MySQL.

Comment: @ITworldR what the issue coming for your query

Comment: @Sachu when i run this quiery I seem to produce the same value for all the average category prices. I have noticed that the second where clause  which manually calculates the average by sum all values/ countof categories greater than >5000 does not produce any results

Comment: @ITworldR  r u running the query only for category Honda and GM?

Comment: @Sachu thank you for our replies, no I am not running it only for Honda and GM that part is for the nested sub-query. The second WHERE clause is suppose to add additional rows to the output based on the average retail category price being more than 5000

Comment: @ITworldR can you show the desired output and the one you are getting now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78392/discussion-between-sachu-and-itworldr).

Comment: @Sachu i have added the desired output above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct..this is what you need to achieve

1. Need to show the average retail price of sedan and suv
2. Need to show the average retail price of other category except sedan and suv if
   sum(stock) /count(category) > 5000

Hope below code can help you

```
select m.name,
       s.category,
       avg(retail) 
 from STOCK s ,
      MANUFACTURER m 
where 
     STOCK.DEALERID=MANUFACTURER.DEALERID 
     and (s.category='sedan' or s.category='suv') 
Group by m.name,s.cateogry 

Union 

select m.name,
       s.category,
       avg(retail) 
from STOCK s ,
     MANUFACTURER m 
where 
   STOCK.DEALERID=MANUFACTURER.DEALERID 
AND (select(sum(retail) from 
            stock s ,manufacturer m 
            where STOCK.DEALERID=MANUFACTURER.DEALERID 
            and (s.category !='sedan' or s.category !='suv') 
      )/ 
       select count(distinct category) 
          from stock s ,manufacturer m 
           where STOCK.DEALERID=MANUFACTURER.DEALERID 
           and (s.category !='sedan' or s.category !='suv') )) >5000 
Group by m.name,s.cateogry
```

You can give `$` symbol and `roundings` as per your wish

there can be better way..but this come to my mind quickly ..try and check